# How to connect firebase to SQL database

Tags: mysql, firebase

I am developing an e-commerce web app. Using firebase auth(email, google and facebook) for project's authtication and mySQL database for data(for example product, order, cart). The problem is how to connect users from firebase auth to other mySQL database's items? for example in mySQL database one user should has many products. So how can we use users from firbase there replace for users in mySQL database and buid a relation with other items in mySQL database? Thanks!

Comment: Using their unique identifiers.

Comment: just take the id of the created user on firebase and use it in your mySql database

Comment: The "connection" is done on application level, not at database level. You store the user id that your application obtains upon authenticating a user in the database in a column of the tables that store data associated with a user.

Comment: how to use these id from firebase in mySQL database?